# Является ли дефис знаком препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, дефис

Прохожу тест, в котором предписывается не использовать знаки препинания, и не могу понять, как писать *из-за, во-первых и т. д.:* как сейчас написал (по правилам) или заменять дефис на пробел.

Прочитал [здесь](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/60840240), что это не знак препинания, но с поставленными дефисами почему-то не получилось тест пройти.

Теперь, кажется, его приняли, возможно, это баг был, что я его не прошёл.

Comment: А что за тест? не скинете ссылочку?  Нужно внимательно читать инструкцию, в некоторых тестах пишут раздельные и полуслитные (дефис) написания слитно

Comment: К сожалению, там надо регистрироваться, чтобы проходить его. Но если несмотря на это интересно, скажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По всей видимости, нет *общепринятого* определения *знаков препинания*, хотя в ряде источников оно имеется и обычно указывает только на те небуквенные знаки, которые используются  на уровне структуры предложения, текста. Пример определения из книги (Словарь лингвистических терминов: Изд. 5-е, испр-е и дополн. — Назрань: Изд-во "Пилигрим". Т.В. Жеребило. 2010): графические (письменные) знаки, нужные для того, чтобы расчленить текст на предложения, передать на письме особенности строения предложений и их интонацию, создать условия для единообразного понимания строения и смысла текста пишущим и читающим. В Справочнике по русскому языку Лопатина определения нет, но дефис рассматривается только в разделе "Орфография", а "знаки препинания" - только в разделе "пунктуация", причём они присутствуют в большинстве его заголовков. В Справочнике же Розенталя нет столь подчёркнутого разграничения: в разделе "Пунктуация" есть глава "дефисное написание" повторяющихся слов.

В аннотации к одной из современных статей по её содержанию высказано следующее:
*Отмечено, что **статус дефиса как пунктуационного знака** не является однозначным у разных авторов. Сделан вывод, что дефис **может** быть отнесен к системе знаков препинания, действующих на уровне морфем и основных графем, а соотносимый с ним знак тире является пунктуационным знаком на текстовом и синтаксическом уровнях.*

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр, за подробный обзор!